# Inserting in sql server from array

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

```
@foreach(var id in myidlist)
{
    message = sql.insertId(userid).ToList();
}
```

I know I can do this, but I really don't want to insert anything if there is a problem while inserting any one data.

For eg.

```
int[] numbers = new int[] {1, 2, 3, a, 5};
```

There is a character so there should come exception but 1, 23 and 234 gets inserted and is not rolled back. I need to use something like transaction.

If its' useful

```
public int insertId(int id)
{
    open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("IDU", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "INSERT");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);

    int res = 0;

    res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    return res;
    close();
}
```

Comment: Can't you just check value with IF and pass it or decline insert?

Comment: yes its possible but , what i'm trying to say is that, if there is any error then i dont want to insert anything.

Comment: Yes, I understood that ... but i just thought it would be better to go through that array first and if everything is fine then send it for insert ... but if you really wanna go with SQL doing that for you, check for Begin and ROLLBACK Transaction

Comment: Please add the DBMS you are using. In SQL Server for example you can pass a table parameter. Other ways may include somekind of "serialization" passing a bunch of values as a concatened string

Comment: ok i'm going for transaction , thanks all

Comment: I think you can do this in more simpler way, if your array has 1000 elements then you have to call your sp for 1000 times , it is not a good practice , you  have to use some other methods , method 1) you can make your array values in to an xml and pass this xml as a parameter to sp and using xquery make it as a table and make update in single step, method 2 ) you can use table valued parameter for this

Answer (score 1):

If you are looping the array and pass each variables to an sp then if array contains many records then it will cause performance issues, because each time you need to contact the sqlserver.

I think the best way is make all of your id values to an xml and pass it to an sp as a parameter and there you can use xquery to process it and simply in one step you can update all values into your destination table, also you can use sql transactions for rollback because you are calling the sp only once and all insertions are happen in same time so if anything will happen wrong then sql server transaction will take care of it.
Method 1)
Example :

an example table for insertion

```
create table tablez1
    (
    id int
    )
```

sp for insertion

```
 IF EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM sys.objects
            WHERE type = 'P'
                AND NAME = 'SpName'
            )
    BEGIN
        DROP PROCEDURE SpName
    END
    GO

    create procedure spname
    @YourXml nvarchar(4000)
    as 
    BEGIN TRANSACTION  

    BEGIN TRY  
    SET NOCOUNT ON
        SET ARITHABORT ON

        DECLARE @iinput XML;

    DECLARE @xmldata XML = @YourXml
       insert into tablez1    

          SELECT id = Adr.value('(id)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')

    FROM @xmldata.nodes('/Root/idvalues') AS Adddress(Adr)

    COMMIT TRANSACTION  
    END TRY  

    BEGIN CATCH  
     SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
      ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity  
      ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState  
      ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure  
      ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine  
      ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage  
    END CATCH  
    GO
```

sample xml as parameter to our sp

```
exec spname '<Root>
    <idvalues>
    <id>1</id>
    </idvalues>
      <idvalues>
    <id>2</id>
    </idvalues>
      <idvalues>
    <id>3</id>
    </idvalues>
      <idvalues>
    <id>a</id>
    </idvalues>
      <idvalues>
    <id>5</id>
    </idvalues>
      </Root>'
```

Method 2)else you can use server side transactions
Method 3)use a table valued parameter

To know more about querying xml data using XQUERY- [READ](http://arunthecodebehind.blogspot.in/2015/12/querying-xml-data-using-xquery-in-sql.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to work with transactions. If an SQL within a transaction fails, none of the commands will be commited. You should read Into transactions on mysql.com

Comment: OP don't stated the DBMS he/she is using

Comment: Oh yes thats right. But in all dbms there are transactions.

Comment: Sure OP is in the right way to try to put that bulk operation in a single atomic transaction but it's not the problem. The problem is how to implement it and it depends if he/she is using Oracle/MS SQL/Postgree...